# Gem for creating a left/right scrollable notification viewer for web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, alerts

I'm new to Ruby on Rails so please bear with me.

I'm creating a web app for users to trade cards and would like to include in the user's home page a notification section that shows relevant alerts for the user based on possible trade matches and other things like new messages. The functionality would require alerts to be generated based on certain triggers (userB accepts trade, trade is proposed to userA, userB messages userA, and possibly even incorporate sponsored posts). This will basically function like the "notification center" on iOS.

I've made a quick mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Av0.jpg (or if that's too big --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1knA.jpg) -- wouldn't let me embed image because I'm new :(

So the idea is the view will probably have 5-15 alerts at any given time (give or take) and can scroll through them using those left/right arrows. The alerts will be a basic message with a link to the relevant page, or for something like a trade rating have the message "open" to fill the viewer and show the necessary functionality.

Hopefully I explained this okay. Anyone know anything out there that might make building this easier? Please let me know if there is any info I missed in asking this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get exactly what your wanting to do but if I understand correctly this may help. I have used [swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/) it is easy to use, should get you started on a swipeable/scrollable interface.